# using $q.all for making synchronous http calls not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

I have encountered the following problem and I am unable to proceed. I tried some of the solutions that were posted in different question, but couldn't get it to work

In my controller, I have a $scope.init() function. I have a for loop in it which calls a function to make http.get calls to different urls, each url depends on the previous call's data, so I need it to be synchronous

```
$scope.init = function() {
    decodedURL = $routeParams.url;

    //evaluate some variables, ampIndex is > -1 here

    for( var i=0; ampIndex > -1; ++i)
    {
        decodedURL = decodedURL.substring(ampIndex+1, decodedURL.length);
        ampIndex = decodedURL.indexOf("&");

        $scope.getNextList(i);
        /* above function call makes the http.get call to the currentURL based on
           decodedURL, and the data is stored in variable[i+1], so for the next
           iteration, the calls should be synchronous
        */

        $q.all(asyncCall).then(function (data) {var j;} );
        /* I wrote the above dummy statement so that it is executed only after
           http.get in $scope.getNextList() function is successful, but it is
           not working 
        */
    }
};


$scope.getNextList = function(index) {

    // $currentURL is calculated
    var hello = _helpers.server.http($http, $scope.currentURL) {
        .success( function(response) {
        })
        .error( fucntion(errResponse) {
        });
    asyncCall.push(hello);
};
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: so the issue is that the call is not synchronous ? Maybe due to $q.all is inside the for loop...

Comment: ya, the call is not synchronous.....I kept $q inside because in each iteration, there is a http call and that should be synchronous

Comment: Why you using $q.all if your asyncCall only contains 1 promise ? Or might be you should refresh your asyncCall to contains 1 promise only ...

Comment: in each iteration, a promise is pushed into asyncCall, is it not right?

Comment: dont think the order will be maintained, check plunkr that i created http://plnkr.co/edit/oL9Lz7NbdVLMnbkpYnQR?p=preview

Comment: You are looking for *sequential* execution, not for *synchronous* one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along these lines?

http://plnkr.co/edit/pjWbNX1lnE2HtaNs1nEX?p=preview

```
$scope.init = function ( ){
  for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.getNextList(i) // push calls into array
  };

  var index = 0;
  function makeCall() {
    $scope.asyncCall[index]
    .success(function(data) {
      if (index < $scope.asyncCall.length - 1) {
        console.log(index);
        index += 1;
        makeCall();
      }
      else {
        console.log(index); // last call
      }
    })      
  }

  makeCall();
};
```